# How to capture data parameter from Ajax call in Restful webservice?

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, rest, spring-annotations

I have a ajax call where I am calling a Restful WS passing a string -

```
var b2bValues = "Some String";  
var lookupUrl = "http://ip:{port}/ImageViewer/rest/ImageServlet/callrest";  
var lookupReq = $.ajax({url:lookupUrl, async:false, data:b2bValues, contentType: "application/xml", type: "POST"});
```

My Restful code is -

```
@POST
@Path("/callrest")
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json", "text/plain"})
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json", "text/plain"})
public ImageFieldsList getImageFromSource(@QueryParam("b2bValues") String b2b)
{//Some code
}
```

b2bValues at Server side is null.

**My Question is how to change Restful code to capture the data parameter passed from Ajax call??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can fix the issue

1. `@QueryParam` will look for the parameters available in the request
   URL. So, if you need to use `@QueryParam` on server-side, you will
   need to modify the URL and send the data as follows:

   ```
   var b2bValues = "Some String";  
   var lookupUrl = "http://ip:{port}/ImageViewer/rest/ImageServlet/callrest?b2bValues="+b2bValues;
   var lookupReq = $.ajax({url:lookupUrl, async:false, contentType: "application/xml", type: "POST"});
   ```

   No changes required on the server side in this case.
2. Usually, for `POST` requests, we send data by forming request
   objects. So, on client-side, you would form the request object like
   this:

   ```
   var requestData = { b2bValues : "SomeValue", 
                       someOtherParam : "SomeOtherParamValue",
                       anotherParam : "AnotherParamValue"
                      }
   var lookupReq = $.ajax({url:lookupUrl, async:false, data:JSON.stringify(requestData), contentType: "application/xml", type: "POST"});
   ```

   And on server-side, you will need to have equivalent value object to
   hold the request data. The names of member variables should match
   the ones you are sending in the request (or vice versa)

   **Sample request object**

   ```
   // SampleRequestObject.java
   String b2bValues;
   String someOtherParam;
   String anotherParam;
   // getters and setters for these member variables
   ```

   Now, the ReST method will change to this:

   ```
   @POST
   @Path("/callrest")
   @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json", "text/plain"})
   @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json", "text/plain"})
   public ImageFieldsList getImageFromSource(SampleRequestObject requestInput) {
   // access request input using getters of SampleRequestObject.java
   // For example, requestInput.getB2bValues();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. But still after making the changes the code is not working. b2bValues is still null.

Comment: I was trying to pass data using your 2nd option. I created the java class also as you suggested and a similar Rest method but it is showing 415 error (Unsupported media type). what needs to be changed?

Comment: Try `data: JSON.stringify(requestData)` while making ajax call.

`var lookupReq = $.ajax({url:lookupUrl, async:false, data: JSON.stringify(requestData), contentType: "application/xml", type: "POST"});`

Comment: As I am using IE8, JSON.stringify() is throwing error "JSON is undefined".

Answer (score 0):

It needs a change in the server code -

```
@POST
@Path("/callrest")
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json", "text/plain"})
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json", "text/plain"})
public ImageFieldsList getImageFromSource(String b2bValues)
{//Some code
}
```

No need to use @Queryparam but the key should match with the variable name.